# Python CSV Saving

Tags: python, file

How to save, please help bro

```
import requests
import csv

movie_url = "https://movie.douban.com/j/search_subjects?type=movie&tag=%E7%83%AD%E9%97%A8&sort=recommend&page_limit=20&page_start=0"

lubao_file =open("lubao.csv","w")

csv_writer=csv.writer(lubao_file)
csv_writer.writerow(movie['title'])

for movie_url in range (0,3):
    douban_url = "https://movie.douban.com/j/search_subjects?type=movie&tag=%E7%83%AD%E9%97%A8&sort=recommend&page_limit=20&page_start=0" + str(movie_url *20)

    head_movie = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"
}


    douban_film = requests.get(url=douban_url,headers=head_movie)
    print(douban_film.status_code)

    if douban_film.status_code == 200:
        json_movie = douban_film.json()
        film_title = json_movie['subjects']

        for movie in film_title:
            print(movie['title'])

        csv_writer.writerow(movie['title'])


lubao_file.close()
```

Comment: Using write functions on `csv.writer()` should automatically write to it (source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). Is there any specific error you're getting?

Comment: This code looks like it should save the csv file.  If there are errors, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
if douban_film.status_code == 200:
    json_movie = douban_film.json()
    film_title = json_movie['subjects']

    for movie in film_title:
        print(movie['title'])

    csv_writer.writerow(movie['title'])
```

My guess is that you want to have `csv.writerow` inside `for` loop? Right now you are only saving the last `movie` inside `film_title`

If thats not it please provide more info about what you are doing, and how its not working (is file empty? is it throwing errors? is it saving only some things?)

Comment: Yes, man. I want to add a file to the loop.  But there is an Error, NameError: name 'movie' is not defined/

Comment: Try moving `csv.writer` inside `for` loop